# Parsing a ddl in Python with regex using re

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove temporary tables from a ddl of over 100 tables by parsing through a file using python and regex. I managed to get the result I want using `'_TMP' in line`, but I desperately want to achieve this with regex. I was having trouble figuring out how to parse over multiple lines, which is impossible if your iterating line by line right?

Example DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE EXNAME.EXTABLE_TMP (
    CONTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
    AFFILIATION_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SEQ_NUMBER NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID,AFFILIATION_TYPE,SEQ_NUMBER)
);

CREATE TABLE EXNAME.EXTABLE (
    CONTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
    AFFILIATION_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SEQ_NUMBER NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID,AFFILIATION_TYPE,SEQ_NUMBER)
);
```

My current solution:

```
f.open('/path/to/file.txt')
copy.open('/path/to/fileCopy.txt')

tmpFound = False

for line in f:
    if '_TMP' in line:
        tmpFound = True
    elif tmpFound == True and ';' in line:
        tmpFound = False
        continue
    if not tmpFound:
       print(line)
       copy.write(line)

f.close()
copy.close()
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: If it is a one-time operation, you can use SublimeText, which support recursive regex syntax to remove _TMP table. Python `re` is not up to the task if you want to write minimal amount of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in your DDL file as a string of SQL statements, then use the [sqlparse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library to parse the string out into a list of separate SQL statements.
From there you can iterate over each SQL statement in the list and use regex to identify CREATE TABLE statements for tables with _TMP in the name.

**Installing sqlparse package via pip**

`(stackoverflow)[joe@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# pip install sqlparse`

**identify_tmp_tables.py**

```
import sqlparse, re

def main():
    with open ('/path/to/file.txt') as ddl_file:
        sql = ddl_file.read()
        ddls = sqlparse.split(sql)
        tmp_tables_regex = re.compile("^CREATE TABLE.*_TMP.*\(")
        for ddl in ddls:
            tmp_table_match = tmp_tables_regex.match(ddl)
            if tmp_table_match:
                print "The following DDL is a TMP table:"
                print sqlparse.format(ddl, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
(stackoverflow)[joe@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# python identify_tmp_tables.py
The following DDL is a TMP table:
CREATE TABLE EXNAME.EXTABLE_TMP ( CONTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL, AFFILIATION_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, SEQ_NUMBER NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID,AFFILIATION_TYPE,SEQ_NUMBER));
```

Comment: This is pretty amazing. Thanks jlyoung! Python has a package for everything.